# How to force SBT to use Java 8?

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I force SBT to compile to Java 8 class files. I added scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8" but it gives the following error message:

```
[error] 'jvm-1.8' is not a valid choice for '-target'
[error] bad option: '-target:jvm-1.8'
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I am using SBT version 0.15.5.

I know I am using Java 8 to compile as I added this to build.sbt, but I still wonder why the scalacOptions fails and I don't know what output the scalac produces.

```
initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  if (sys.props("java.specification.version") != "1.8")
    sys.error("Java 8 is required for this project.")
}
```

Comment: Decompiling one of my Play view classes reveals the format version to be 50 - which is not Java 8, so my previously posted answer was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sbt doesn't do anything in this regard, `scalac` is responsible for creating JVM targeted artifacts. You instruct `scalac` to use intended version by using `scalacOptions`. Sbt only passes options given by `scalacOptions` to the scala compiler (i.e. `scalac`). Since newer versions of `scalac` deprecated `-target` flag, sbt gives you such an error.

As of Scala 3.2.2, the correct `scalacOptions` flag for the same purpose is `-java-output-version`. So it becomes:

```
scalacOptions ++= Seq("-java-output-version", "8")
```

Answer (score 45):

You need the following on your build.sbt file.

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value
  val javaVersion = sys.props("java.specification.version")
  if (javaVersion != "1.8")
    sys.error("Java 1.8 is required for this project. Found " + javaVersion + " instead")
}
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to get the value of the `initialize` setting?  Just good practice in case a parent build has initialization?  (New to sbt here.)

Comment: I'm seeing this a lot, but isn't `javacOptions` just for compiling Java source files, within sbt? `scalacOptions` is what matters for the scalac compiler.

Comment: You also probably want "`scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.8")`", as @akauppi points out.

Comment: To newcomers (esp. Windows), make sure that both the PATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables have been updated to use respectively jdk8\bin and jdk8

Comment: `javacOptions` is for compiling Java source files within `src/main/java` and `src/test/java`. It has nothing to do with Scala source files, the correct answer should use `scalacOptions`.

Answer (score 19):

Support in scalac for jvm-1.8 was added in 2.11.4.

Scala version (2.11.2) does not support `-target:jvm-1.8` option.

```
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL

$ scala -target
Usage: -target:<target>
 where <target> choices are jvm-1.5, jvm-1.6, jvm-1.7 (default: jvm-1.6)

bad option: '-target'

Usage: scala <options> [<script|class|object|jar> <arguments>]
   or  scala -help

All options to scalac (see scalac -help) are also allowed.
```

Comment: Seems to be the valid answer. What if I want to use a Java library which is compiled for Java 8 and only works in Java 8, can I use that from my generated Scala 7 bytecode? I guess the answer is yes. Sorry this is a different question but I'm trying to use a Java library which only works in Java 8 from my Scala code.

Comment: Additional Information for the IntelliJ user:

If you get `Problem extracting project structure` from your IntelliJ IDE, this can be due to incorrect or missing targeting of the Java version especially if you have multiple versions of Java present in your environment or upstream tree branches be sure to try above answer.

Comment: As of scala 3.2.2, the correct flag for the same purpose is `-java-output-version` i.e. `scala -java-output-version 8`, the `-target` flag is deprecated right now.