# Using Java 8 in Scala 2.11

Tags: scala, java-8

I wanted to know if it is possible to use [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in java 8 in my scala 2.11 program?

then how to add it to my sbt project?

Comment: If you're compiling with java 8 you should be able to "just use" it. Don't think you need to add anything to SBT.
Did you try that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force SBT to use Java 8?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926111/how-to-force-sbt-to-use-java-8)

Comment: @antoine-sac No, it is not a duplicate of that. This question clearly shows that the OP is a scala and sbt beginner who is trying to understand the use of Java libs in sbt projects.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Right, I got misled by the answer.

Comment: As @DenisRosca mentioned, if you are comipling it with jdk 8 then you can just import it in your code.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to add anything to your project. `java.time` is a standard part of Java, not an external third-party dependency.

You just need to make sure that your customers run your code on Java 8.

This has nothing to do with SBT. SBT is a *Build Tool*. It is about how you *compile* your code. But your problem is that you need to control how your customers *run* your code. You could do that simply by stating in your documentation that your code only works with Java 8+ and hope that your customers actually *read* that documentation. You could use a launcher that checks the Java version before running the main code and prints out a suitable error message.

Comment: Hi, I am using scala 2.11.5 but can't import java.time..Is this supported by my scala version?

Comment: `java.time` is a part of Java. It has nothing whatsoever to do with Scala. It even has "Java" in its name! Your Scala version is completely and utterly irrelevant. If you have Java 8, you have `java.time`. If you don't have Java 8, you can't use it. It doesn't matter if you are using Scala 2.11.5, Scala 2.11.8, Scala 2.12, Scala 1.0, Clojure, Groovy, Kotlin, Ceylon, Fantom, Ruby, Python, JavaScript, PHP, Scheme, CommonLisp, Java, or any other language.

Answer (score -2):

> Until Scala 2.12 comes along, Java 6, 7, or 8 can be used with any of
>   its inbuilt packages and `java.time` is an inbuilt package.So can be
>   used. However newest release Scala 2.12, will support Java 8 only.So any case yes it **can be used in Java 8**.

If you explicitly want this package in Scala you have to add Java.time dependency to sbt file.On maven central its replaced by Joda-time.Its an individual Java.time Api provided by Apache.

It can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time

> To use it add:
>
> ```
> (
> libraryDependencies += Seq( "joda-time" % "joda-time"    % "2.3"
>                            , "org.joda"  % "joda-convert" % "1.6"
>  // other dependencies 
>                            )
> ```
>
> to you sbt file.

joda-convert is needed for Scala compilation of Joda-time.It actually converts objects to and from Strings.

> **NOTE**:If you explicity want to use java.time Scala implementation find [Scal-Java-time](https://github.com/soc/scala-java-time/blob/master/build.sbt) link on Github.