# How to generate a jar file that is able to run on Java 1.7, with sbt and Java 1.8

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt

I have to compile a Spark program which runs with Java 1.7. However, I have Java 1.8 installed on my computer. My code has both Scala and Java classes, and I compile using sbt. I know you that one can set target with javac, but since I compile using sbt, and therefore don't directly call javac, how can I compile such code for Java 1.7, with Java 1.8.

P.S: I don't want to separately install Java 1.7 on my computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25926111/how-to-force-sbt-to-use-java-8

Comment: Java is backward compatibile, so you can compile with source level 1.7 using Java 8

Comment: You mean If I don't use any Java 1.8 specific feature, my jar file is gonna run fine on Java 1.7 VM, even if I compile it with Java 1.8?

Comment: Yes, but you must specify language level in javac options - see answer that I've linked

Comment: I was using Java 1.8 in project that has language level 1.7 and it worked ;) Just don't use Java 8-specific features and set compiler options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is backward compatible, which means you can compile to Java 7 bytecode using Java 8 compiler

In sbt you must manually set target Java version:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7", "-target", "1.7"),
scalacOptions := Seq("-target:jvm-1.7")
```

It will tell javac and scalac to set Java 7 class headers

References: [first](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/targeting-java-platforms-with-sbt) and [second](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206635525-How-to-set-a-target-java-version-with-a-sbt-project-)

Comment: As of scala 3.2.2, the correct flag for the same purpose is -java-output-version i.e. `scalacOptions ++= Seq("-java-output-version", "8")`, the -target flag is deprecated right now.